# tell tar to ignore sockets - I don't want to see warnings

Tags: tar, socket

I have this warning message about sockets with tar:

> ERRO[0000] Can't add file
>   /home/ubuntu/backup-db/.bunion.sock to tar:
>   archive/tar: sockets not supported

how can I tell `tar` that I don't care?

Comment: What implementation of tar are you using? it appears to be possible in GNU tar using `--warning=no-file-ignored`

Answer (score 1):

`--exclude` is the [command line option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html).

Comment: umm like ``--exclude=pattern'`?

Comment: does the pattern of --exclude support file _modes_? could you use it to exclude sockets, no matter what their name is?

Comment: I don't think so. For something like that, I'd use `find` piped into a file and use that as the list of files to tar, _e.g._ `tar Jcvf myfile.tar -T <(find . -type f)` (untested of course)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `tar` or libarchive's `bsdtar`, you could do:

```
find backup-db ! -type s -print0 |
  tar --no-recursion --null -T - -cf - |
  nice pixz > backup-db.tar.xz
```

With `bsdtar`, replace `--no-recursion` with `--no-recurse`. The `star` equivalent would be something like `tar c -f - -read0 list=-`.

That is get `find` to take the list of files to archive  and exclude those of type *`s`ocket*.

As noted by @steeldriver, with GNU `tar`, you can also use the `--warning=no-file-ignored` which suppresses warnings about unknown or unsupported file types such as *sockets* or *doors*.